# is it possible to achieve dynamic scheduling of a task for each user at different time in spring boot/java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

We have an REST API  "/schedule" for scheduling a call to 3rd party API . when one User login and set his scheduler time to 1 minute for a task then it is set for every user (using shceduledExecutorService with method name scheduleAtFixedRate)

```
TaskUtils mytask1 = new TaskUtils(this);

            scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

            futureTask = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask1, 0, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but this is not the actual requirement. Let's understand the requirement with an example.
**Example & Requirement : user1 login and  schedule a task at a time difference of 1 minute . when user2 login he want to scheduler the task at 1 hour. So, execution should be like that the scheduled task execute at different time for different users.**

Comment: Surjeet, you are adding a lot of requirements/examples in your comments to answers that should be part of the question. You should clarify the goal from the outset. As it stands, the question can be answered by a simple "yes, it is possible", which (by your comments) does not appear to be your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the appropriate amount of time to the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method.

You already have a variable for that purpose shown in your code: `time`.

You are specifying milliseconds as your unit of time. Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class to convert from minutes or hours to milliseconds.

```
long time = Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ).toMillis() ;
```

Or from hours to milliseconds.

```
long time = Duration.ofHours( 1 ).toMillis() ;
```

Or any arbitrary amount of time specified using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) notation. Here is one and a quarter hours.

```
long time = Duration.parse( "PT1H15M" ).toMillis() ;
```

Set up your executor service somewhere.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Set up your task somewhere.

```
Task task = new TaskUtils(this);
…
```

Write a method to be called for each new user.

```
FutureTask scheduleTaskForUser ( Duration timeToWaitBetweenRunsForThisUser ) {
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0 , timeToWaitBetweenRunsForThisUser.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    return scheduledFuture ; 
}
```

Alice logs in and says she wants a 5 minute period.

```
String input = … ;  // For example, "PT5M".
Duration d = Duration.parse( input ) ;
ScheduledFuture sf = scheduleTaskForUser( d ) ;
user.setScheduledFuture( sf ) ;
```

When Bob logs in, run the same code for his user object.

Later, Alice wants to change the amount of time. Call another method, `rescheduleTaskForUser( Duration timeToWaitBetweenRunsForThisUser )` on the user-session tracking object for Alice. That method accesses the stored `ScheduledFuture` object for Alice, cancels that future, schedules the task again, and returns a new `ScheduledFuture` object to be stored on the user-session tracking object for Alice.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering my question. i already manage to do it . Requirement : User1 pass 1 hour . User2 pass 2 hour. How to make scheduler run for both at their given time.

Comment: @SurjeetSinghRathore **Your code already does just that.** Each time you submit a task for each user, you are passing the period between executions of that task.

Comment: sir you are right ,but at the same time user1 is unable to change his task execution time. Example user1 set execution time to 1 hour . user2 set it to 2 hour , what happen when user1 want to change his execution time from 1 hour to 4 hour? how he can change it ?As we have nothing to figure out that this is the scheduled time of user1 .Or there is any other way to do it.

Comment: @SurjeetSinghRathore (a) Your Question did not ask about *changing* a scheduled task's period. (b) To change the period, capture the [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object returned by [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Cancel that future object. Then schedule your task again, this time with a different period.

Comment: can we identify future object uniquely ? or should i go for current thread id . As your comment gives very generalized answer. i think identifying future object for particular user to be needed to end a scheduled task for that user. What is your take on that. Further comments Will be appreciated

Comment: @SurjeetSinghRathore Well, just basic Java: Track each `ScheduledFuture` object per user. I added some example code to walk you through a user’s login where you determine each user’s desired amount of time, you schedule a task for that user, capture and remember that task’s `ScheduledFuture`, then later reschedule the task by canceling the future object and scheduling the task again to get a new `ScheduledFuture` to be stored on that user’s own user-session object. No thread identifiers needed, as it is not your job to juggle threads, that is the job of an executor service.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time. Your answer is helpful.